# Access default JAXB marshaller used for JAXRS resource method

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a number of REST resource classes that return a model entity and rely upon JAXRS to convert to XML automatically (without my own custom Provider).  I want to be able to access the JAXB marshaller instance used for this so I can configure a ValidationEventHandler to catch exceptions.  How do I do this?

Here is my sample entity resource:

```
@Path("/device")
public class DeviceResource extends CaBridgeServletResourceManager {
    /**
     * Get the server status.
     */
    @GET
    @Path("/config")
    public DeviceConfigurationResponse getDeviceConfigurationResponse() {
        DeviceService service = new DeviceService(getSessionContext());
        DeviceConfigurationResponse response = service.createConfigurationResponse(getDeviceCredential());

        return response;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
        Marshaller marshaller = ... get jaxrs default marshaller ...
        marshaller.setEventHandler(new MyMarshallerEventHandler());
```

How do I get the default marshaller used by jaxrs?  Or is there a new marshaller instance I can access for each instance of my resource class (above)?

I would rather avoid creating custom Provider classes for every entity class I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a ContextResolver and it will get used:

```
@Provider
public class JaxbMarshallerProvider implements ContextResolver<Marshaller> {
    @Override
    public Marshaller getContext(Class<?> type) {
    }
}
```

And the same thing for the Unmarshaller. We generally instantiate the JAXBContext once and stash it in a static member in the provider class.